# Silverlight local storage equivalent in HTML 5

Tags: html, silverlight, local-storage, indexeddb, fileapi

I want to store config on the client's computer that is persisted per device (not per browser) and access it across all HTML 5 enabled browsers. I can store this config with Silverlight's [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts8hk0(v=vs.95).aspx) where all browsers with this plugin can read it. The shortcoming I see with (my understanding of) the following HTML 5 technologies

Local Storage : [Data will be deleted if user clears cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948284/how-persistent-is-localstorage)
IndexedDB: [Data won't be shared across browsers](http://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2012-10-05-indexeddb-storage.html)
File API: [Can't read any arbitrary file without permission of user.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251432/read-a-local-file-using-javascript-html5-file-api-offline-website) The user might have to drag and drop the file for me to be able to read it, I am going to store some configs in the file, so I wouldn't want the user to drag and drop the file every time I want to read the config

Is there any project that can help me or some "design pattern" that I can use in such scenarios? 
Should I be looking at something outside HTML 5?

Went through the following with no success:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/156682/how-to-move-silverlight-app-to-html5
https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills
http://www.manasinc.com/silverlight-and-html5-comparison/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to persist data if the user clears the cache, the only way to even come close is to store the data on the server side (in relation to a user profile) and then upon the app connecting and sending parameters (such the user agent and screen res) re-download the specific config into cache.

Furthermore i doubt there is a way to achieve full compatibility with every web browser (as is with most cases) however in terms of storage web storage is the method most compatible with current browsers. http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage

Answer (score 0):

```
// To save (Silverlight Out of browser)
// This code is used when you have a Silvelight runs out of browser and typical local storage won't work, you can create an xml file saved on local c drive and retrieve that data when restarting the app.

XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                new XElement("Root",
                    new XElement("userinit", "john doe")
                ));
string path = "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\setup.xml";
using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter(path))
{
    doc.Save(writext);
}    

// to read, read the same file you save to the saved setup
string path = "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\setup.xml";
//<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
//<Root>
//    <userinit>john doe</userinit>
//</Root>
// from the xml you can extract your saved data
string result = sting.Empty;
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    System.IO.StreamReader read = new StreamReader(path);
    result = read.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: My answer above is for out of browser Silverlight application.

Answer (score 0):

```
// for in browser app
// to save 
// you can create a local storage file in the form of xml
// this file will persist as long as you don't clear the browsing history
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
            new XElement("Root",
                new XElement("userinit", "john doe")
            ));
using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("setup.xml", FileMode.Create, isoStore))
    {
        doc.Save(isoStream);
    }
}
// to read
// the saved xml will be
//<Root><userinit>john doe</userinit></Root>
// you can extract data from there
// 
string lineOfData = String.Empty;
using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    if (!isf.FileExists("setup.xml"))
        return;
     using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("setup.xml", FileMode.Open, isf))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(isfs))
            {

                lineOfData  = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
       }
 }

// get the data from xml
string initials;
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(lineOfData);
var q = (from c in xdoc.Descendants("userinit")
                     select c).Single();
            _Initial = q.Value;
            initials = _Initial;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to that code such that others can learn from it